# Calculating and storing the division between current row and previous row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I wanted to calculate the fractional difference between x(current value) and x(previous value) and store it into a new Pandas row for a huge table.

| ID | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1400 |
| 2 | 1500 |
| 3 | 1600 |

fractional_diff = (1500 / 1400) - 1

End Result should look something like this where first row is 0:

| ID | x | fractional_diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1400 | 0 |
| 2 | 1500 | 0.071428571 |
| 3 | 1600 | 0.066666667 |

I did try the following code by the way...

```
# Dataframe if anyone needs it real quick:

data = [['1', 1400], ['2', 1500], ['3', 1600]]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'x'])


# Initialize the variables

n = 1
# data['fractional_diff'] = 0

# for loop to calculate fractional_diff for all rows:

for values in data['x']:
    data['x'][n] = (data['x'].loc[n] / data['x'].loc[n-1]) - 1
    n = n + 1
    
    if n > len(data['x']) - 1:
        break;

data.head()
```

But for some reason I keep getting traceback errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df.x/df.x.shift() - 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Let us do [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) on column `x`

```
df['change'] = df['x'].pct_change().fillna(0)
```

---

```
   ID     x    change
0   1  1400  0.000000
1   2  1500  0.071429
2   3  1600  0.066667
```